# Facebooker log out logs user out of facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebooker, facebooker2

Is it possible to log out of a Facebooker app without logging the user out of Facebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. Log out from application always logs out the user from FB itself. That is how their API works.